# How to import data to a remote neo4j server?

Tags: neo4j

I have developed a simple application which performs CRUD operations on my local embedded neo4j server.I have initialized the server like this.

```
public static final Strin DB_PATH=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/neo4j/data/graph.db";
public static final GraphDatabaseService ourGraphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

Now I want to run my crud operations in a remote server. Firstlly I want to check if i can successfully import data in my local server (localhost:7474/db/data).

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a server extension that has direct access to the embedded database of Neo4j server. Then you expose your domain level REST endpoints to your client applications.

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint.

docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use REST Service. Rather i want to just access my neo4j database in the remote server directly. As i am completely new i am still wondering if theres a way.

Comment: You can also use a remote driver, like the Neo4j JDBC Driver: http://neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc